# Why does my sim with a clock never finish?

Tags: simulation, verilog

I added a clock generator to my module, and now the simulation never finishes.

```
always #10 clk = ~clk;
```

Why does the sim not finish after all `initial` code is done?

```
module test;

  reg clk;

  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    $display("Hello");
  end

  always #10 clk = ~clk;

endmodule
```

Sim results on EDA Playground: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using an `always` block, you need to have `$finish` statement in one of your `initial` blocks to finish the sim.

Fixed code:

```
module test;

  reg clk;

  initial begin
    clk = 0;
    $display("Hello");
    $finish();  // <-- FIX
  end

  always #10 clk = ~clk;

endmodule
```

Sim results here: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/16

That said, if you also have a SystemVerilog `program` in your environment, the sim will automatically finish after all the `initial` code in your `program` blocks is done. From section 24.3 of [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) standard:

> When all initial procedures within a program have reached their end,
>   that program shall immediately terminate all descendent threads of
>   initial procedures within that program. If there is at least one
>   initial procedure within at least one program block, the entire
>   simulation shall terminate by means of an implicit call to the `$finish`
>   system task immediately after all the threads and all their descendent
>   threads originating from all initial procedures within all programs
>   have ended.

Comment: Also `$stop` statement might be useful

Comment: @Qui, `$stop` statement does not end the sim, but suspends it. From the standard: _The $stop system task causes simulation to be suspended._ Here is the test on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/18). That said, some simulators, like VeriWell, will finish the sim when `$stop` is called.

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky: I'm aware how `$stop` statement works. I've just pointed out that it also might be useful (e.g. if you don't want to close simulator after simulation is completed (ModelSim)).

Comment: @Qui, I apologize. I didn't know what you meant by "useful".

Answer (score 1):

There's no fundamental difference between `initial` and `always`: `always` is just `initial forever`. As long as anything is scheduled for future execution, then the simulation will continue (unless it is explicitly stopped); your statement continuously re-schedules the clock assignment, so the sim never stops. There really is *nothing* special about `initial`: it's not even guaranteed to run before any `always` blocks.

This wasn't an SV question (which I know nothing about), but I was interested to see VL's comment about automatically finishing the sim when the initial code is finished. This would break Verilog compatibility, and I'd be interested to see an LRM reference that confirms this.

Comment: I added LRM reference in my answer.